# Получение JSON по ссылке

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, visual-studio, discord-api

Я работаю над ботом в discord js и Visual Studio Code.

Делал функцию загрузки JSON с ссылки.

### Но когда почитал, то нашёл вариант с JQuery

```
$.getJSON( "https://httpbin.org/get?method=search&api_version=1.0&api_key=test_api_key&query=discovery", function( data ) {
      console.log(data);
});
```

---

Но в Visual Studio Code выдавало ошибку:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Comment: Подключите библиотеку JQuery и ошибка пропадет.

Answer (score 1):

```js
fetch("https://httpbin.org/get?method=search&api_version=1.0&api_key=test_api_key&query=discovery")
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вы забыли подключить JQuery.